# Creating image of AWS workspace fails without explanation

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, amazon-workspaces

My end goal is to migrate my workspace to a newer bundle, but first I have to make a image of my current workspace. Both creating a image as making the migration straight up, are failing.

I have this workspace Launch Bundle: Standard with Windows 10 and Office 2016 Pro Plus (Server 2016 based) (PCoIP) It runs alright but i wanted to migrate to this one: Standard with Windows 10 (Server 2019 based) I did the imageChecker.exe test and all passes. But then i try to migrate, stays for a while pending, even changes the Operating system tag to Windows Server 2019, but in the end turn back to the 2016. I presume some error, but there is no notification and i don`t know where to go from now. Someone can help me?